# Crypto protfolio tracker in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, portfolio

**Background:**
I created a crypto portfolio tracker with googlesheets to see it together with my stock portfolio.For stocks, googlesheets has a built-in formula to show the stock's current value.
For cryptos, I used importhtml formula and typed in one of the crypto exchanges' website.
Example:
=index(importhtml("https://www.coingecko.com/hu/coins/"&A7; "table"; 1); 1; 2) A7 is the name of the crypto, i.e. ethereum.

**Problem:**
At random events I get error message, that It cannot show me the value >> #N/A.
Comment says it cannot call the URL.
Each time the crypto is different, meaning, today it cannot show ethereum, tommorow it will, but won't show bitcoin. There is no logical pattern in which is not working.

I tried to do it with different html, but the issue is the same.

Could you help me solving this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It'll be better to use JSON, do coingecko have an API? because HTML is changing all the time

Comment: Paste the code making the requests (only the relevant lines mind you), and the results from the Network Tab.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div/span/span[@data-target='price.price']"), 1)
```

[image]